# How to convert jersey/jackson list to String in response

Tags: list, serialization, jersey

I have a List type field populated using solrj where it marshals data directly to bean using getBean() method. The solr field is marked as multivalued but it really is single valued. In the rest response I want to transmit it as a single string. Here is the code

```
@XmlRootElement
@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Record {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Field //solrj field populated based on schema type
    private List<String> titleList;

    public String getTitle() {
        if(titleList!= null && titleList.size() > 0) {
            return titleList.get(0);
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

When I get the response object from non jersey rest clients I see the 'title' field populated correctly as String but with jersey REST client I get it as empty String. How can it be correctly deserialized as derived value for all REST clients?

I am getting value from java client as

```
Record response = target.queryParams(queryParams).request().buildGet().invoke(Record.class);
```

Chrome Rest client output
{
      "title": "new trend",

jersey client output
{
    "title" : "",

Answer (score 0):

I used @JsonIgnore on both getter and setter methods instead of field. That worked for both deserialization and serialization

```
@Field("title")
    private List<String> titleList;

@JsonIgnore
public List<String> getTitleList() {
    return titleList;
}

@JsonIgnore
public void setTitleList(List<String> titleList) {
    this.titleList= titleList;
}

public String getTitle() {
    if(titleList!= null && titleList.size() > 0) {
        return titleList.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```